# change from recurrence relation to iterative approach

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

An investment of 1,000,000 receives a 10% bonus every year. A total of $48,000 is withdrawn from the investment each year. Assume that you have got the 10% bonus before you withdraw each year.

I just got the recurrence relation which is s(0)=1000000,and s(n)=1.1xS(n-1)-48000. I need the iterative approach (or so call the explicit formula ). Thanks.

Comment: What is the iterative approach?

Comment: means the formula that we can get the answer straight without referring to the previous number value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $T=1,000,000$, $W=48 ,000$, and $q=1.1$.
With these notations we have:
$$
\begin{matrix}
\text{ after the first withdrawal:}& T q -W\\
\text{ after the second withdrawal:}& Tq^2 -Wq-W\\
\text{ after the third withdrawal:}& Tq^3 -Wq^2-Wq-W\\
\vdots\\
\text{ after the }\  n^{th}\  \text{withdrawal:}& Tq^n -W\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}q^i.
\end{matrix}
$$

A closed form of the sum above can be obtained like this. (Let $S_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}q^i$.) Then

$$S_n-qS_n=1-q^n,$$

or

$$S_n=\frac{\ 1-q^n}{1-q}.$$
So, after the $n^{th}$ withdrawal, we have

$$Tq^n-W\frac{\ 1-q^n}{1-q}.$$

Comment: how did you get " Sn−qSn=1−qn " ??

Comment: $S_n=1+q+q^2+\cdots +q^{n-1}$, $qS_n=q+q^2+q^3+\cdots +q^{n-1}+q^n$ $\rightarrow$ $S_n-qS_n=1-q^n$ because all the other terms cancel out.